# c++ program to watch directory for alterations

Tags: c++, c, linux, directory

I am looking for a way to make a program in C or C++ that detects if there was any files altered, renamed, moved or deleted in a specified directory for Linux systems. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want [inotify](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8478) (and its [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify).)

Comment: Thanks, i will explore this possibility too

Comment: Well, I will go with this one

Answer (score 4):

Look into [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify), I think it's still current.

You can also use a wrapping API, such as glib's GIO [GFileMonitor](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gio/stable/GFileMonitor.html).

Answer (score 3):

Program against [FAM](http://oss.sgi.com/projects/fam/). On current Linux systems this service is provided by gamin or a similar application.

Comment: I *think* FAM is deprecated, and that you should use inotify instead. Am I right?

Comment: FAM as a program is deprecated, but its *interface* is still provided by gamin.

Comment: Thanks, i will explore this possibility

Comment: Is there any reason to use gamin instead of inotify directly? (cross-platform compatibility maybe?)

Comment: Yes, cross-platform compatibility would be the big reason. Not to a lot of platforms mind you, but better than just recentish versions of one.

Comment: gamin is better than inotify because it is higher level. A c++ wrapper would be even better.
poco for example includes a directory watcher class - http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.DirectoryWatcher.html
Including poco just for this however would be overkill.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use Qt and its QFileSystemWatcher class which can be used quite easily.

Comment: Well I am quit a Qt user, but for this program I wanted to use something more like Inotify, but thanks!